# Jquery Auto complete item selection is being appended 3 times

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI autocomplete framework for my jQuery Mobile application .

The code is working fine, but the issue i am facing is that, when i enter some characters under the field `iamat`, it is fetching the data from back-end and populating it to the field, when i select one of the option, it is 
again appended to the  `iamatsearch`, this is repeated for 3 times and after 3 times everything is fine .

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <label class="fieldLabel">I am at</label>
    <input type="text" id="iamat" name="iamat" onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event)" required/>
    <div class="autoSearch_result_Wrap" id="iamatsearch" name="iamatsearch"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
     <label class="fieldLabel">Table No.</label>
     <input type="text" id="tablenum" name="tablenum" onkeypress="return nospecialCharacters(event)" required/>              
</div>

$(function() {    
    $("#iamat").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
      var iamat = $.trim($("#iamat").val());
      if (iamat) {
         $.ajax({
           url: url + '/ouu/ooo/autosuggestvendornames?vname=' + iamat,
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           timeout: 6000,
           cache: false,
           jsonp: false,
           jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback'         
           success: function(data) {
              var result = [];
              jsondata = data;
              for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
              {
                  result.push(data[i].vendor_name)
               }    
             response(result);
          }         
        });
       }
    },
    minLength: 2,
    appendTo: "#iamatsearch",
    select: function (event, ui) {

    }
  });
});
```

This issue is not repeated under browser, so i am not pasting a fiddle.
could anybody please let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: Try replacing `$(function()` with `$("#yourpageid").on("pagecreate", function()`. In jQuery Mobile  `$(document).ready()` is quite unpredictable (better avoid it)

Comment: Can I see your results page?